# How to set the width with no value before the 5

Tags: c++

How do I make the entire second line of the output right aligned in the output? I believe it is set to right align, but I feel like a need a variable to represent a blank space before it outputs the five. If someone can try to run this program to see the output display I am talking about it would make a lot more sense to whoever reads this.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <cmath>

    using namespace std;

    int main() { 

        cout<< "Temp | -------------- Wind Speed --------------" <<endl;

        for( int w=5; w<=45; w=w+5) {
            cout << setw(10) << right << w;

        }
        cout<< endl;

        for (int t=-5; t<=50; t=t+5) {
            cout << setw(5)<< right << t;
            for(int w=5; w<=45; w=w+5){
              cout << setw(10) << right << fixed<< setprecision(1)<< 35.74+(0.6215*t)-35.75*pow(w,0.16)+(0.4275*t*pow(w,0.16)); 
            }
            cout<<endl;
            }

        }
```

Comment: What is the output you get? What is the output you want?

Comment: Do you want the `5` in the second line to align with the `-16.4` on the third line?

Comment: I want the 5 to align with the -16.4, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <cmath>

    using namespace std;

    int main() { 

        cout<< "Temp | -------------- Wind Speed --------------" <<endl;

        cout << "     ";

        for( int w=5; w<=45; w=w+5) {
            cout << setw(10) << right << w;

        }
        cout<< endl;

        for (int t=-5; t<=50; t=t+5) {
            cout << setw(5)<< right << t;
            for(int w=5; w<=45; w=w+5){
              cout << setw(10) << right << fixed<< setprecision(1)<< 35.74+(0.6215*t)-35.75*pow(w,0.16)+(0.4275*t*pow(w,0.16)); 
            }
            cout<<endl;
            }

        }
```